# create an image with a string randomly placed around the center

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to create an bunch of images that are very simple, just a string on a white background.

I would like the string to be located at a random position in the image, around the center and so that the whole string is visible (i.e. none hidden outside the image limits).

The strings are generated automatically, so I don't know their length beforehand, I just know they will be within a given range of lengths (6 - 15 chars).

For this I'm working with imagemagick's convert, and this is what I got atm:

```
convert -background "#ffffff" -size 800x480 -fill "#000000" -pointsize 72 -gravity Forget label:'mytext' output.png
```

which renders this:
[image: rendered image]

`gravity` seems to influence the location of the label, but there's no random option for it.

Comment: What OS do you use please?

Comment: I have ox x - ImageMagick 7.1.0-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Ok, I think you can draw the text and trim it to within an inch of its life, then pad it with 50px of white all around and place that randomly on your final canvas:

```
#!/bin/bash

bd=50   # 50px white space around letters
ps=72   # pointsize of letters
fh=480  # final height
fw=800  # final width
tmp="/tmp/$$.mpc" # temporary file

# Generate the text with padding all round so it can't touch edges and get its size
read w h < <(magick -pointsize $ps label:"$1" -trim -bordercolor white -border $bd -write "$tmp" -format "%w %h" info:)
echo "DEBUG: Text requires ${w}x${h} px"

# Work out random x,y offset from top-left where to place text
((x=RANDOM%(fw-w)))
((y=RANDOM%(fh-h)))

magick -size ${fw}x${fh} xc:white "$tmp" -geometry "+${x}+${y}" -composite result.png
```

Then you would save that as `doit` and make it executable with:

```
chmod +x doit
```

Then call it with:

```
./doit "Your text"
DEBUG: Text requires 381x153 px
```

`result.png`

[image]

Here's an animation of 100 frames:

[image]

**Original Answer**

Here's a basic template that draws your text at offset +50+20 from the centre in your image:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:white -fill black -pointsize 72 -gravity center -annotate +50+20  "My Text" result.png
```

[image]

---

You can then randomize the `+X+Y` coordinates (also using `-X-Y` if you want the position offset above and to left of the centre-point instead of below and right) using your shell. Something like this:

```
for ((i=0;i<20;i++)) ; do 
  ((X=RANDOM%80))
  ((Y=RANDOM%80)) 
  magick -size 640x480 xc:white -fill black -pointsize 72 -gravity center -annotate +${X}+${Y}  "My Text" miff:- 
done | magick -delay 80 miff:- animated.gif
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot, tested it and my strings go a lot out of the boundaries, both right and left.

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you actually want to achieve please? You can change the `RANDOM%80` to `RANDOM%40` and never go further than 40 px from the centre instead of 80 - is that what you mean? Are we allowed to change the font size? How near does the text need to go to the edge of the image? How random is it supposed to be?

Comment: I have a bunch of random strings of size between 6 and 15 characters, I would like to have them all over the place (with some 50px margin to the border, so they are never right on it), they should all have the same font and size.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I could generate a first image with the text centered, then get the size of the bounding box, and use this size to regenerate the image with different coordinates. or even crop the first image and add it to a white image at coordinates calculated similar to above

Comment: fantastic, thanks for the update, this works perfect

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

In Mark Setchell's answer, one can also use the ImageMagick internal fx:rand() operation to do the random offsets. The rand() function returns a value between 0 and 1.

```
magick -size ${fw}x${fh} xc:white "$tmp" -geometry "+%[fx:($fw-$w)*rand()]+%[fx:($fh-$h)*rand()]" -composite result.png
```

Comment: Yes, indeed In fact, you can probably make it into a one-liner if you think about it long enough.

Comment: Perhaps use -set option to create the dimensions for the text (w,h).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-line command to do what you want in ImageMagick 7. This is based upon Mark Setchell's answer with the addition of using -set option to save the text image size and the use of the ImageMagick rand() function to do the randomization. Note that -set option variables may be used in fx computations.

```
bd=50   # 50px white space around letters
ps=72   # pointsize of letters
fh=480  # final height
fw=800  # final width
text="THIS IS A TEST"
magick \
\( -background white -fill black \
    -pointsize $ps -gravity center label:"$text" \
    -trim +repage -bordercolor white -border $bd \
    -set option:ww "%[fx:$fw-w]" \
    -set option:hh "%[fx:$fh-h]" \) \
-size ${fw}x${fh} xc:white +swap \
-gravity northwest \
-geometry +"%[fx:%[ww]*rand()]"+"%[fx:%[hh]*rand()]" \
-composite result.png
```